# My controller is making form data NULL using codeigniter3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

This is my form :

```html
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo base_url('Usercontroller/insert') ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apartament</label>
    <input type="text" name ="txtApartament" class="form-control" id="txtApartament" placeholder="Apartament">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Status</label>
        <select name ="txtStatus" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach($getStatus as $value) { ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $value->per_id ?>"><?php echo $value->status_name;?></option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nume</label>
    <input type="text" name ="txtNume" class="form-control" id="txtNume" placeholder="Nume">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Persoane</label>
    <input type="text" name ="txtPersoane" class="form-control" id="txtPersoane" placeholder="Personae">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Mp</label>
    <input type="text" name ="txtMp" class="form-control" id="txtMp" placeholder="Mp">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Comentariu</label>
    <input type="text" name ="txtComentariu" class="form-control" id="txtComentariu" placeholder="Comentariu">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Salveaza</button>
</form>
```

And this is my controller insert function side:

```
public function insert() {
    $datai= $this->input->post();

    if(isset($datai)){
        $txtApartament = $datai['txtApartament'];
        $txtStatus = $datai['txtStatus'];
        $txtNume = $datai['txtNume'];
        $txtPersoane = $datai['txtPersoane'];
        $txtMp = $datai['txtMp'];
        $txtComentariu = $datai['txtComentariu'];
        $this->Usermodel->insertUser($txtApartament,$txtStatus,$txtNume,$txtPersoane,$txtMp,$txtComentariu);
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

Model side:

```
public function insertUser($apartament, $status, $nume, $persoane, $mp, $comentariu){

    $arrayDates = array(
        'apartament' => $apartament,
        'per_id' => $status,
        'nume' => $nume,
        'persoane' => $persoane,
        'mp' => $mp,
        'comentariu' => $comentariu
    );

    $this->db->insert('membri', $arrayDates);

}
```

When I will submit on my forum I will get this :

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'apartament' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `membri` (`apartament`, `per_id`, `nume`, `persoane`,     `mp`, `comentariu`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: models/Usermodel.php

Line Number: 28
```

Also this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: txtApartament

Filename: controllers/Usercontroller.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File:   /var/www/html/adminigniter1/application/controllers/Usercontroller.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/adminigniter1/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

When my controller gets the data, will make it NULL, my form is passing the data correctly(checked the headers), what can be the issue on the controller side ?

And yes, I have set the helper with url and form!

Comment: Show us your table structure.

Comment: Are you getting redirected in the middle of the request? you may want to add a condition to your isset() block to see if it is a POST/PUT request.

Comment: I guess he has table structure issue . .

Comment: if you put 'var_dump($datai); die();' after $datai= $this->input->post(); what $datai look like?

Comment: @DannyThunder I tryed that also and I will get array(0) { }.

Comment: @Punit.. I don't think it's tablet related problem since the data is not getting there with a valid format, my controller will make it NULL. But here is it my structure : http://oi64.tinypic.com/rr1ht2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, wasn't from my code, it was apache2 ...

in the rewrite.load file in apache, I added the line :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And it worked!

Comment: So it was a redirect :)